# How does the sum of two operators act on a two-level system of qubits?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I am confused how the sum of N operators will act on an N-level system of qubits. Here, lets say N=2 so the state is $|00⟩_{CD}$. Then how will this operator $ X_{C} + Z_{D} ⊗ I_{C}  + X_{D}$ act on this state?

Is it distributive like this:
$ (I _{C} + X_{D}) |00⟩_{CD} = I_{C}|00⟩_{CD} + X_{D}|00⟩_{CD} = |00⟩_{CD} + |01⟩_{CD}$?

And then $ X_{C} + Z_{D}$ would act on each of the terms ($|00⟩_{CD}$ + $|01⟩_{CD}$) above, giving 4 terms?

Some intuition on how/why this happens would be appreciated. How can you construct the sum of the matrices of $I _{C}$  and $X_{D}$?

Answer (score 1):

The sum of operators in your question:

$$\tag{1}
 X_{C} + Z_{D} ⊗ I_{C}  + X_{D},
$$

is actually this:

$$
X_C \otimes I_D + I_C \otimes Z_D + I_C \otimes X_D.\tag{2}
$$

To get how this behaves on the state $|00\rangle$ you just have matrix addition and multiplication: $(A + B + C)|00\rangle$.

You get 3 terms: $ |10\rangle , |00\rangle , |01\rangle $.

I don't see how you could get the 4th term ($|11\rangle$) when there's nothing flipping both qubits at the same time.

Comment: +1. But should the last term be $I_C \otimes X_D$?

Comment: @KAJ226 yup. i did it on my phone while still in bed.

Comment: hahaha...   :)  nice!

Comment: $(X_C \otimes I_D + I_C \otimes Z_D + I_C \otimes X_D)$ - how did you arrive at this?

Comment: @lethobentho whenever you see an operator acting on only one qubit, please understand that there's an identity operator acting on all other qubits. However, you have made a major change to your question which now makes my answer incorrect, so I will have to rollback that change. On some sites it might be fine to keep changing the question after answers are written, but on this site answers are not well-rewarded, see this: [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16313/generally-speaking-are-quantum-speedups-always-due-to-parallelization-of-a-give/16319#comment22794_16313).

Comment: So once I've written an answer, I don't want to change it to conform to future edits to the question. I would be glad to give you another answer if you ask another question though. You could ask this question but with the brackets there, and ask about whatever you don't understand in my answer here :)

Comment: In this case, so you suggest me to post this question but with the parentheses as a separate question?

Comment: @lethobentho That would probably be closed as a duplicate, even though I might have time to answer it before it gets closed. My suggestion would actually be to try to understand my answer, then if you don't get it, ask a separate question about the part that you don't understand in my answer. Surely you do understand why I have two X and one Z, but perhaps you don't understand why the identity operators are in the places where they are. So you could ask why this answer has those, and then give your more complicated example which is the product of 2 binomials rather than just one trinomial.

Comment: I understand your answer at the moment but I do not understand if it will be the same with the parentheses in the question.

Comment: To add onto this, I am unsure whether you would "expand" the expression for the operator, like for example, you would do: $ (a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd $, hence why I asked whether there would be 4 terms in the original question

Comment: @lethobentho  $(A+B) \otimes (C+D) = A \otimes C + A \otimes D + B \otimes C + B \otimes D $. But what you wrote seems to indicate that  you have $A + B +C$ where $A = X_C = X_C \otimes I$, $B = Z_D \otimes I_C$ and $C = I_C \otimes X_D$.

Comment: I agree with @KAJ226 . Thanks for taking over while I was gone :)

Comment: @KAJ226   Thanks, my apologies for the confusion around editing the question. To clarify, if you extend this to 2 tensor products, e.g. $ (A + B) \otimes (C + D) \otimes (E + F) $, would this result in 8 tensor products?

Comment: @lethobentho Yes.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: What you have written is more or less correct and your result will indeed give 4 terms, however it is not a valid quantum operator.**

Firstly, I will add brackets to your operator to make it $(X_C + Z_D) \otimes (I_C + X_D)$. Given that, let us take just focus on just the $(I_C + X_D)$ term and work it through. We will see that, as you mentioned, $(I_C + X_D)|00\rangle_{CD} = |00\rangle_{CD}+|01\rangle_{CD}$.

To begin we first have to take into account what was pointed out by @user1271772: "whenever you see an operator acting on only one qubit, please understand that there's an [implicit] identity operator acting on all other qubits". Explicitly, all this means is

$$
I_C = I_C \otimes I_D \\
X_D = I_C \otimes X_D \\
$$
Now let us construct the matrices of the above two operators

$$
\begin{align*}
I_C &= I_C \otimes I_D =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align*}
X_D &= I_C \otimes X_D =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
If the above computations of tensor products of matrices are unfamiliar to you, have a quick read through the [Wikipedia page on Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Now, writing $|00\rangle_{CD}$ in matrix form $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0\\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}$, we can perform the multiplication to get
$$
\begin{align*}
(I_C + X_D)|00\rangle_{CD} &= \left[(I_C \otimes I_D) + (I_C \otimes X_D)\right]|00\rangle_{CD} \\
\\
&= (I_C \otimes I_D)|00\rangle_{CD} + (I_C \otimes X_D)|00\rangle_{CD} \\
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0\\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} = |00\rangle_{CD}+|01\rangle_{CD}
\end{align*}
$$

**However** all that being said, the operator $(I_C + X_D)$ is actually not a valid quantum operator. This is because it is non-unitary. This can be seen by taking the its determinant which is given by

$$
\begin{align*}
|I_C + X_D| &= \left| \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\right| \\ 
&= \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = 0
\end{align*}
$$
So in fact you cannot ever perform the operation $(I_C + X_D)$ on a quantum computer.

The exact same steps can be taken with the other term in your original question $(X_C + Z_D)$ and you will find a similar situation - i.e. the math will work out but the operator will not be a unitary one.

Comment: But they are valid Hamiltonian operators and those can act on the 2 qubit state too. Also why did you ad those brackets there? That's not what the original question had.

Comment: (1) I added the brackets to try and clear up what was meant, because the way it was written it wasn't so clear because. Another possibility might be $(X_C \otimes I_C)+(Z_D \otimes I_C)+(I_C \otimes X_D)$? But if that's the case then you've already answered the question in your answer.
(2) They are individually valid operators, but the addition of two valid operators isn't necessarily a valid operator. However in the way you have written it, it could be that there's just a normalization factor missing in which case it isn't that big a deal.

Comment: Thanks. My question was meant to be merely illustrative of the concept I needed clarification on (the brute math behind it) so whether it was unitary or not didnt matter in this context but thanks for the clarification regardless!